# How to bring facebook connect button in login form?

Tags: 7, users, social-network

For one of my projects I installed the Facebook O Auth module in my site. Now I would like to display the Connect with facebook in my login form.

Comment: It will be god if you use gigya module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to alter both form using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and add a markup field with value `fboauth_action_display('connect')`

```
$form[fb_connect] = array(
   '#markup' => fboauth_action_display('connect'),
);
```