# Remove default tab from login page ( Simple Fb Connect)

Tags: 7, social-network

I am using [Simple FB Connect](http://localhost/myproject/user/simple-fb-connect) module for Facebook login in my site. It adds a tab for facebook login, by default in my Login page. I want this tab to be removed and add a button instead. How can I remove this?

Comment: This other [SE thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34361/how-to-bring-facebook-connect-button-in-login-form?rq=1) might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Create a hook_menu_alter function like this in a module:

```
function my_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
  unset($items['user/simple-fb-connect']);
}
```